# MySql and Post Method

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm Inserting data using method post to MySql database, but I don't want to insert duplicated data in this database.

I used this:

```
$insertar="INSERT INTO datos(`nombre`, `cedula`, `Correo`, `telefono`, `ptd`) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['Nombre']."','".$_POST['Identificacion']."','".$_POST['Email']."','".$_POST['Telefono']."','".$_POST['ptd']."')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nombre=nombre AND cedula=cedula AND Correo=Correo AND telefono=telefono and ptd=ptd;";

$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar) or die ('Error en el query database- insertar datos');
```

but it gives me this mistake:

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg9rh.png)

I need: if the value already is in the database do nothing and continue normally.

Comment: May I recommend StackOverflow en Español: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Maybe space between your parentheses and ON solve your problem

Comment: Here is great explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`